# Providing a sensitive API key to testthat

Tags: r, testthat

I'm attempting to setup mocking of an API to increase the test coverage of an API package I maintain (https://github.com/condwanaland/scrobbler)

Installable with

```
remotes::install_github("condwanaland/scrobbler")
```

I've used httptest to record the results of hitting the API

```
library(httptest)

capture_requests({
  download_scrobbles(.limit1 = TRUE)
})
```

`capture_requests` stores the result of this request in json files. The mock then loads this file in place of making the actual request

In `download_scrobbles()`, the API username and key are loading via environment variables

`Sys.getenv('LASTFM_API_USERNAME'); Sys.getenv('LASTFM_API_KEY')`

However, I then have setup a snapshot test to check that the output remains the same

```
library(httptest)
library(testthat)

with_mock_api(
  {
    test_that("Output is producted correctly", {
      local_edition(3)
      expect_snapshot_value(
        download_scrobbles(.limit1 = TRUE),
        style = "deparse")
    })
  }
)
```

However, since `testthat` doesn't have access to my `.Renviron` file it fails with

```
'LASTFM_API_USERNAME' and/or 'LASTFM_API_KEY' environment variables are not set.
         Set them with 'Sys.setenv() or pass these variables explicitly.
```

I cant pass these parameters explicitly because then they would get checked into git and reveal the username and api key.

How can I either:

1. Give testthat access to my local `.Renviron` file when run interactively (I'll skip the test when non-interactive), or
2. Provide a `.Renviron` file to testthat in a way that doesn't require checking something into git or being built by R CMD BUILD, or
3. Any other option I haven't considered?

Comment: Using a call to the *real* API in your test makes the test dependent on factors outside your control.  (What if the endpoint of the API is down for some reason?  or if the format of its return value changes?)  Shouldn't you be mocking `download_scrobbles()` itself, rather than its return value?

Comment: @Limey when used with `with_mock_api` all the requests are intercepted and replaced with the jsons recorded via `capture_requests`. So no API call is made in the test. Theoretically I could pass any parameter values in, however `with_mock_api` then cannot find the json files generated (it uses the request url to match requests to captured jsons)

Comment: OK.  I'm not familiar with `httptest` and then misinterpreted your description of the test.

Comment: OK.  A further thought - since no API calls are actually made, does `with_mock_api` actually need the *real* crednetials?  Could you perhaps just pass fake values?

Comment: Yep, I thought that as well. Unfortunately you need to pass the exact same request to both with_ and capture_, otherwise with_ will not load the results from capture_

Answer (score 1):

I was able to find an answer to this. If you just supply a fake password to the test it throws an error because it cant find the mocked files:

```
with_mock_api(
  {
    test_that("Output is producted correctly", {
      local_edition(3)
      expect_snapshot_value(
        download_scrobbles("condwanaland", "mocked", .limit1 = TRUE),
        style = "deparse")
    })
  }
)
```

```
Error: GET http://ws.audioscrobbler.com/2.0/?method=user.getRecentTracks&user=condwanaland&limit=1000&api_key=mocked&format=json&page=1&from=0 
(ws.audioscrobbler.com/2.0-699785.json)
```

However, the last part of that error (`ws.audioscrobbler.com/2.0-699785.json`) tells you the file name that `httptest` is looking for. By renaming the existing json file to match the expected one, the test passes.